# onMouseEnter isn't working for me - React

Tags: reactjs, onmouseover

I even tried it in an online react sandbox so clearly I'm doing something wrong here.
It's the same with onMouseOver and onMouseLeave. It fires on first render and then never again.
I want when I hover over an element to log to the console.

```js
import React from "react"



const Parent = () =>{
  const handleMouseEnter = () =>{
    console.log("mouse entered")
  }

  return(
      <>
        <div onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} className="w-[50px] h-[50px] bg-green-500" >Hello</div>
      </>
  )};

export default Parent;
```

Comment: does not look like it may be your Parent component is not rendered again ?

Answer (score 0):

It was because there was no callback function inside the onMouseEnter.

```
onMouseEnter(handleMouseEnter())
```

changed to:

```
onMouseEnter(()=>{handleMouseEnter()})
```

Works fine now

```js
import React from "react"



const Parent = () =>{
  const handleMouseEnter = () =>{
    console.log("mouse entered")
  }

  return(
      <>
        <div onMouseEnter={()=>{handleMouseEnter()}} className="w-[50px] h-[50px] bg-green-500" >Hello</div>
      </>
  )};

export default Parent;
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, both statement should and do produce the same output. Your original code works so I don't understand the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-nwgre3?file=/index.js

Comment: I removed the classes and the fragment from the example just because they're irrelevant, there's no foreseeable reason it shouldn't work with them included..

Comment: I have no Idea why it worked now and not before. You're right it has the same output. The original snippet is exactly what I used. Today I put in a callback function not even thinking about it and now it works. It was the only change I made. I don't know why this happened. I don't know what I did wrong initially so I'm still confused.

Comment: It's because you need to pass the reference to the function, not call the function.